# Is it possible to change a series of attributes with jQuery asynchronously?

Tags: jquery

If I have the following:

```
<img src="filler.jpg" class="imgClass" delays="otherImage.jpg" delayw="400" delayw="600" delayt="Loaded">
<img src="filler.jpg" class="imgClass" delays="otherImage2.jpg" delayw="450" delayw="600" delayt="Loaded 2">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgClass").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("delays"));
        $(this).attr("width", $(this).attr("delayw"));
        $(this).attr("height", $(this).attr("delayh"));
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("delayt"));
     });
})
```

Is there a way I can have the width, height and title attributes only change after the src attribute has finished changing?  With the above code they seem to all change at the same time.  In a perfect world I'd like them to happen one at a time.  At a minimum I'd like the src to change then the other three to change right after that since the src changes takes a slight bit of time.

Comment: *"In a perfect world I'd like them to happen one at a time."* Changing any of the attributes (apart from `src`) happens instantly. Could it be that you want to animate the changing the width and height?

Comment: @FelixKling not animate, just remove a jarring bit of display change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` event is triggered after the image was retrieved:

```
$(".imgClass").each(function(){
    this.src = $(this).attr("delays"));
}).one('load', function() {  // `.one` executes the event handler only once
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr({
        width: $this.attr('delayw'),
        height: $this.attr('delayh'),
        title: $this.attr('delayt')
    });
});
```

Assigning values to the DOM properties is often preferred over assigning to HTML attributes, so you might want to consider using `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: @gdoron I've never seen anyone bother before, but it should help garbage collection and reduce memory usage.

Comment: @gdoron: I just thought it seems to be a one time thing. Using `.one('load')` now instead.

Comment: BTW, I *think* this code may have problems on browsers that don't like it when you register the event handler _after_ changing the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `.onload` callback.  Here's a version without jQuery:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('imgClass');
for (var i = 0, n = img.length; i < n; ++i) {
     var el = img[i];
     el.onload = function() {
         this.width = this.getAttribute('delayw');
         this.height = this.getAttribute('delayh');
         this.title = this.getAttribute('delayt');
     };
     el.src = this.getAttribute('delays');
});
```

NB: for greater HTML5 compatibility, use `data-foo` attributes instead of making up your own.

Comment: Why mixing vanilla JavaScript with jQuery ?

Comment: Because often vanilla JS is far more efficient, and no less verbose.  Sometimes it's even _less_ verbose, e.g. `this.src` vs `$(this).attr('src')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
$(".imgClass").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("delays"));
        $(this).on('load',function(){
          $(this).attr("width", $(this).attr("delayw"));
          $(this).attr("height", $(this).attr("delayh"));
          $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("delayt"));
        })
})
```

;